# How can I pass a value to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
retrieveData();
```

and then javascript code like this:

```
var retrieveData = function ()
        {
            function () { $('#updater').show(); }
            $.post('......
```

This is I think a simple question but how can I pass an argument to the retrieveData function and have it availabe for use in the code following the .post ?

Comment: That's a rather odd style of formatting you got there ... `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
var retrieveData = function (a) {
   $.post(...);
   // use `a` here
}

retrieveData("some value");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var retrieveData = function (answer) {
  $.post('The answer is ' + answer);
}

retrieveData(42);
```